# bool function return issue

Tags: c++, c++11

Now I realise I need a bool function, not a void function, how do I get this function to return 0 or 1?

```
bool Alist::remove(int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
   if(a[i] = n)
    {
      for ( int j = i; j < (val - 1); j++)
        a[j] = a[j+1];
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
   if(a[i] != n)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

my code runs fine but doesn't print this statement;

```
cout << "Double remove: " << a1.remove(n) << " " << a1.remove(n) << endl;
```

Comment: Is the return value of `a1.remove` `void`?

Comment: yes @StephenNewell

Comment: Your error is that you're trying to pass `void` to `operator <<`.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, but can I not continue with it being void? im not sure what it should return if its not void. @StephenNewell

Comment: What exactly do you want printed? The code attempts to print the return value of `a1.remove(n)` call, which makes no sense as that call doesn't return any value (that's what `void` means).

Comment: I see your point, I am meant to make a class and class functions around a test set, so I must make it an int type then and not a void type. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, actually maybe bool would work better, I can see it is meant to return a 1 or 0

Comment: What are you trying to print?  The contents of `a1` after each remove, or whether the removes succeeded?

Comment: @StephenNewell I see I made an error trying to make it void, I've made it bool now, trying to return 1 or 0. should I make my return, "return true;"

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to pass `void` to a function that accepts a `const Alist&`. If you call the `remove` function, but don't return anything from it, then what should the function print? It cannot print void, since the definition of void is that there is no memory, no bits that are stored anywhere. A possible fix (if its what you're trying to accomplish) would be to `return *this;` at the end of the `Alist::remove` function, so that your printing function(operator<<) has something to print.